# Importing a Dreamweaver Project into CFBuilder

Tags: dreamweaver, coldfusionbuilder

I have a Dreamweaver project created with Dreamweaver CS3 and need to import it into CFBuilder 2.0. When I do this, CFBuilder creates a new Project folder and adds a "1" to the folder name. That of course breaks links to other files in the project when they are located in a different folder.

How can I IMPORT the Dreamweaver Project into CFBuilder? It doesn't need to work in Dreamweaver in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to Import an existing Dreamweaver project into ColdFusion Builder:-

1. Open the Import wizard. This is accessible from the main menu by going to File > Import or by right-clicking within either the Project or Navigator panels and selecting Import from the context menu.
2. Expand the ”Other” directory in the list and select “Existing Folder As New Project” and click Next to proceed. Open an existing folder as a new project.
3. Browse to the location of the folder containing the project and select the root directory. Specify the location of the folder and the root directory. Rename the project, as you wish.
4. At this moment, the project has been imported into ColdFusion Builder, but it contains no properties or references of a ColdFusion project. Right-click on the project folder and select Properties to display the dialog window. From here, you can see there is no reference to ColdFusion in the left-hand menu. Close the properties window.
5. Right-click the project folder once again and select “Apply CF Nature.” The icon for the folder in the Project panel should change to display the initials “CF” to confirm that the nature has been applied to the project.
6. Right-click the project folder once more and select Properties again. You can now see the ColdFusion options in the left-hand menu. Select “ColdFusion Server Settings” and either add a new server or select an existing server to apply to this project. Click Apply to save any changes.

Hope this helps.